# Why does Rider open Visual Studio when a Verify test fails?

Tags: rider, verify

I currently work on the [GildedRose](https://github.com/emilybache/GildedRose-Refactoring-Kata) kata and decided to replace ApprovalTests with [Verify](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify).

Whenever the Verify test case fails, Rider tries to open *.received.txt in Visual Studio. Not only is that unwanted behavior, but the Visual Studio process crashes.

Why is this happening? Is there a hidden setting somewhere I have missed? I have also installed the Verify plugin for Rider, but nothing changes.

Comment: Could that be OS file extension association?

Comment: The test result file which is produced is .txt, so I don’t think so. But worth checking out.

Comment: Try asking in https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/issues
maybe?

Comment: There I was asked to go here :-D

Comment: I would say then: repoduce the problem and call Help->Report a Bug (in Rider), agree to attach logs. Reference your question written in https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/